# Kube-prometheus-stack : No Data for Node resources except one node

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I deployed kube-prometheus-stack on a k8s cluster 1.21, with 3 control plane and 8 worker nodes, no changes in values.

All pod start fine, I found all node-exporter pod on all nodes, but checking Node related dashboard, stats are shown only for 1 node, also 1 istance of Node Exporter is shown.

[image]

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.